# Oracle PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type 06550

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to use the id value that is retrieved from my select and is what my loop is based on in my insert statement.  Both the id from the select and the second column in the TEST_LOG table are NUMBER(19,0).  When I replace id with 12345 it works fine.  Any ideas?

```
BEGIN
  FOR id IN
  (SELECT id FROM t_sample where children is null)
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO TEST_LOG VALUES (my_sequence.nextVal, id, 'sample', current_timestamp);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Error:

```
Error starting at line : 6 in command -
BEGIN
      FOR id IN
      (SELECT id FROM t_sample where children is null)
      LOOP
        INSERT INTO TEST_LOG VALUES (my_sequence.nextVal, id, 'sample', current_timestamp);
      END LOOP;
    END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 5, column 69:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Id should be referred in the insert as `id.id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The confusion is understandable.
Better you write in this way, and the error will shine.

```
...
FOR record IN
      (SELECT id FROM t_sample where children is null)
      LOOP
        INSERT INTO TEST_LOG VALUES (my_sequence.nextVal, record.id, 'sample', current_timestamp);
      END LOOP;
...
```